# Custom grouping on Dataset

Tags: sas

I have the following data that's grouped according to the variable 'node'. I want to collapse some of the data into groups. Is there a more elegant way of doing it than the following:

```
    proc sql;  
create table delete
       (t0avgStakeRank num,
        eventtime num,
        previousnode char(10),
bettors num);
quit;

proc sql;  
insert into delete                                                                                                                 
(t0avgStakeRank, eventtime, previousnode, bettors)                                                                                         
    values(0,1,' ',1000)
    values(0,2, 'L',500)
    values(0,2, 'W',500)
    values(0,3, 'LL',250)
    values(0,3, 'LW',250)
    values(0,3, 'WL',250)
    values(0,3, 'WW',250)
    values(0,4, 'LLL',125)
    values(0,4, 'LLW',125)
    values(0,4, 'LWL',125)
    values(0,4, 'LWW',125)
    values(0,4, 'WLL',125)
    values(0,4, 'WLW',125)
    values(0,4, 'WWL',125)
    values(0,4, 'WWW',125)
    values(0,5, 'LLLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWWW',62.5)
    values(1,1, '',1000)
    values(1,2, 'L',500)
    values(1,2, 'W',500)
    values(1,3, 'LL',250)
    values(1,3, 'LW',250)
    values(1,3, 'WL',250)
    values(1,3, 'WW',250)
    values(1,4, 'LLL',125)
    values(1,4, 'LLW',125)
    values(1,4, 'LWL',125)
    values(1,4, 'LWW',125)
    values(1,4, 'WLL',125)
    values(1,4, 'WLW',125)
    values(1,4, 'WWL',125)
    values(1,4, 'WWW',125)
    values(1,5, 'LLLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWWW',62.5);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
quit; 

proc sort data=delete; by t0AvgStakeRank; run;
proc tabulate data=delete missing;
    title ' ';
    var bettors;
    class t0avgstakerank eventTime previousnode;
    table t0avgstakerank=""*eventTime=" "*(previousnode=" "), bettors*sum;
run;
```

This is how I've been doing this up to now so that I can aggregate the sum across the groups.

```
proc sql;
create table grouped as 
select distinct
t0avgstakerank,
eventtime,

case when previousnode in ( 'LW', 'WL') then "LW/WL"
when previousnode in ( 'LLW', 'LWL', 'LWW') then "LLW/LW*"
when previousnode in ( 'WLL', 'WLW', 'WWL') then  "WL*/WWL"
when previousnode in ( 'LLLW', 'LLWL', 'LLWW','LWLL') then "LLLW/LLW*/LWLL"
when previousnode in ( 'LWLW', 'LWWL','LWWW','WLLL','WLLW','WLWL') then "LWLW/LWW*/WLL*/WLWL"
when previousnode in ( 'WLWW','WWLL','WWLW','WWWL') then "WLWW/WWL*/WWWL"
else previousnode  end as previousnode_grouped,

case when previousnode in ( 'LW', 'WL') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ( 'LW', 'WL') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
when previousnode in ( 'LLW', 'LWL', 'LWW') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ( 'LLW', 'LWL', 'LWW') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
when previousnode in ( 'WLL', 'WLW', 'WWL') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ( 'WLL', 'WLW', 'WWL') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
when previousnode in ( 'LLLW', 'LLWL', 'LLWW','LWLL') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ( 'LLLW', 'LLWL', 'LLWW','LWLL') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
when previousnode in ( 'LWLW', 'LWWL','LWWW','WLLL','WLLW','WLWL') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ( 'LWLW', 'LWWL','LWWW','WLLL','WLLW','WLWL') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
when previousnode in ( 'WLWW','WWLL','WWLW','WWWL') then (select sum(bettors) from delete as sub where previousnode in ('WLWW','WWLL','WWLW','WWWL') and sub.t0avgstakerank = main.t0avgstakerank) 
else bettors end as bettors_grp

  from delete main;
```

quit;

Comment: I would write a format that collapses the groups how you want them.  It's not apparent to me what the pattern is, but the code is at least as short as the above and probably shorter if there's any pattern.

Comment: Will do if the values will sum up in the groups. The pattern just collapses a standard 1*2*4*8*16 decision tree into a 1*2*3*4*5 Pascal's triangle kind of tree.

Comment: Perhaps then sort the L/Ws in a new variable, then PROC SORT by that, then use the original LWL whatever as START and LLW (sorted) as LABEL in PROC FORMAT.